# How to fix Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History'

Tags: reactjs, react-router, webpack-4

I have this little app that works fine in development mode with webpack-dev-server, but when I use the bundled files from the dist folder generated by the production mode, all I get in the browser is this error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'file:///C:/' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null' and URL 'file:///C:/Users/cristi/work/react_test_ground/dist/index.html'.
```

How can I solve this pushState problem?

Initially I tried to split the code with React.lazy and Suspense, since webpack was throwing this error:

```
WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets:
  2c7b7b6becb423b8f2ae.bundle.js (413 KiB)

WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
Entrypoints:
  main (413 KiB)
      2c7b7b6becb423b8f2ae.bundle.js


WARNING in webpack performance recommendations:
You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of
your application.
```

But the problem persists.

You can see the code and the full repository here: https://github.com/cristiAndreiTarasi/temporary

**App.js**

```
import React, { Fragment, Suspense, lazy } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

const Home = lazy(() => import('./Home'));
const Blog = lazy(() => import('./Blog'));
const Contact = lazy(() => import('./Contact'));

export default () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><Link to='/'>Home</Link></li>
                <li><Link to='/blog'>Blog</Link></li>
                <li><Link to='/contact'>Contact</Link></li>
            </ul>

            <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading...</p>}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                    <Route path='/blog' component={Blog} />
                    <Route path='/contact' component={Contact} />
                </Switch>
            </Suspense>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>   
);
```

**The format of the other components is this one:**

```
import React from 'react';

export default () => (
    <div>
        <h1>Hello from the Blog</h1>
        <img src='../images/landscape-art_large.jpg' />
    </div>
);
```

I want to get the same result that I,m getting from the development mode, from the bundled files generated by the production mode.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should open your files via an Webserver. Because you cannot change location history on the file:// api.

Comment: I was able to make it work with XAMPP on the localhost, but after I had uploaded the same files on the public_html with FileZilla I get the same problem. Do you have any sugestion about how I could make it work on my portofolio website on the hosting provider's server? I'm with justHost. Thank you.

Comment: Did you open the page via ftp:// protocol? Because you should open the page direktly. HTTP://example.tld

Comment: This works, After serving the build folder from the web server, no errors, and working properly.

Answer (score 9):

You can use **HashRouter** or **MemoryRouter** instead BrowserRouter.

Just replace this line:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
```

with:

```
import { HashRouter, Route, Link, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
```

or with:

```
import { MemoryRouter, Route, Link, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Then open your builded index.html file in the browser and everything should work like using localhost / dev server.

Answer (score 3):

I had this error (notwithstanding at my react app) because i provided instead of searchParams **url**, i put the whole url into the history.pushState `http://localhost:9090/admin/model-type?PageNumber=2`
but search query is expected `?PageNumber=2`

```
history.pushState(
        {[paramKey]: paramValue},
        'page title',
        url
      )
```

Comment: This worked for me and makes a lots of sense when you think about it