# Deploy ReactJs App as static app for use on USB stick

Tags: reactjs, deployment

I want to deploy ReactJS App that should be run from usb stick. Is it enough to copy all files from "Build" directory to stick after
`npm run build`
command in terminal? It seems OK for me after I fixed some paths manually. I am asking is this metod OK or there is better way to deploy apps for such usage?!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all files from build directory is enough to deploy a react app. it's about the web server you used for this purpose.
Read this links, may to help you:

1. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/
2. https://dev.to/xarala221/the-easiest-way-to-deploy-a-react-web-application-2l8a

Comment: I have major issue.. in this case Router doesn't work! When I try to navigate I get following error: ... 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL..

Comment: How did you run the project after build from dist directory?

Comment: I just copied content from Build directory and opened index.html.. I didn't use any server because, as I noted, it should be running from USB memory stick!

Comment: When you run react app with `file://...` protocol, you'll get this error. Read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55881641/how-to-fix-uncaught-domexception-failed-to-execute-pushstate-on-history)

Comment: This means I can't run React app with routes properly without server :/ I have to find workaround for routing.